# HSQLDB hangs in Jboss and Maven Surefire

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have a fairly simple application that I am using to store a few key value pairs. I decided to use HSQLDB for this, and have a very basic unit test that starts the database, creates some tables, then exits. This runs fine in eclipse, but hangs in maven surefire, with the following reported by stack. This is consistent every time I run the test.

Unfortunately, the same deadlock is present if I go ahead and run my application in jboss, so the problem is not with surefire. I have tried the various row locking options, with no effect.  Has anyone seen and hopefully got past this? I am running hsqldb version 2.3.2 under java 1.7.

```
"HSQLDB Timer @53063e86" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f140cfa7800 nid=0x1d77 in Object.wait() [0x00007f13e2da7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000783b0a678> (a org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue.park(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0000000783b0a678> (a org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer.nextTask(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0000000783b0a678> (a org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: You need to report the connection URL and also what your application does after it connects.

Comment: I am using the file: database, and after connection the test creates three tables and an index then exits.

Comment: Perhaps there are 2 HSQLDB processes running in the VM. The HSQLDB Timer is a singleton with a single thread.

Comment: This might well be it - I have certainly seen jboss starting one up, although it would be surprising if maven did. It could be that it is multithreading the tests themselves.